# Flutter Firestore batch write with setDate and merge

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am using following code in Flutter to write to Firestore. In case document exists, I need data to merge with old fields.

```
var batch = Firestore.instance.batch();
batch.setData(
   db.document('Path/to/firestore/document'),
   {"key": value},
    );
```

To add merge I tried this code, but its not working:

```
var batch = Firestore.instance.batch();
batch.setData(
   db.document('Path/to/firestore/document'),
   {"key": value},
   {bool merge: true}
    );
```

If anyone can suggest me how to add **merge:true** option to **batch.setData()**, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you copied the text `{bool merge: true}` right out of the [API docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/WriteBatch/setData.html).  That `bool` is just telling you the type of the field `merge`.  It's not supposed to go in your code.  Just use `merge: true`.

```
batch.setData(
   db.document('Path/to/firestore/document'),
   {"key": value},
   merge: true
);
```

**UPDATED**

```
batch.setData(
   db.document('Path/to/firestore/document'),
   {"key": value},
   SetOptions(merge: true)
);
```

Comment: I tried with {merge: true}. Its saying, Too many positional arguments. 2 expected but 3 found.

Answer (score 0):

In Recent Update of Firebase You can use like this.

```
WriteBatch batch = FirebaseFirestore.instance.batch();
DocumentReference userRef = reference.doc(userId);
batch.set(userRef, mapData, SetOptions(merge: false));
```

Update Your batch.setData to batch.set()